# Layered current category

Tags: magento-1.7, category, layered-navigation

I need to implement category navigation left sidebar and show only current category and children. I add `left_nav.phtml`.

```
<?php
$object = new Mage_Catalog_Block_Navigation();
$actualCategoryId = $object->getCurrentCategory()->getId();
$actualCategory = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($actualCategoryId);
$subCategories = explode(',', $actualCategory->getChildren());

?>
<div class="vertnav-container">
    <h1><?php echo $actualCategory->getName(); ?></h1>
    <ul>
    <?php
    foreach ( $subCategories as $subCategoryId ) :
        $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($subCategoryId);
        if ( $category->getIsActive() ): ?>
            <li><?php echo '<a href="'.$category->getURL().'">'.$category->getName().'</a> '; ?></li>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
</div>
```

But problem is when I clicked on subcategory, it's show only name, cause subcategory don't has children. But I need to show Parent and children, when I click on it.
Thanks.

**ANSWER:**

```
if ($actualCategory->getData('level') != 2) {
    $actualCategory = $actualCategory->getParentCategory();
}
$subCategories = explode(',', $actualCategory->getChildren());
```

I made it like this, but I open for another answers ;)

Comment: Please write your solution as an answer.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation :(

Comment: Do you have enough now, or how many do you need?

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry but to have an answer here (added by Stopper himself)

```
if ($actualCategory->getData('level') != 2) {
    $actualCategory = $actualCategory->getParentCategory();
}
$subCategories = explode(',', $actualCategory->getChildren());
```